# Delete a row from a dataframe if its column values are found in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df1 = {
    'vouchers': [100, 200, 300, 400],
    'units': [11, 12, 12, 13],
    'some_other_data': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    }
df2 = {
    'vouchers': [500, 200, 600, 300],
    'units': [11, 12, 12, 13],
    'some_other_data': ['b', 'd', 'c', 'a'],
    }
```

Given the two dataframes like above, I want to do the following: if voucher from `df1` can be found in `df2`, and their corresponding unit is the same, then delete the entire voucher row from `df1`.

So in this case the desired output would be:

```
df1 = {
    'vouchers': [100, 300, 400],
    'units': [11, 12, 13],
    'some_other_data': ['a', 'c', 'd'],
    }
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this efficiently with index operations, using `pd.Index.isin`:

```
u = df1.set_index(['vouchers', 'units'])
df1[~u.index.isin(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df2.vouchers, df2.units]))]

   vouchers  units some_other_data
0       100     11               a
2       300     12               c
3       400     13               d
```

Answer (score 3):

Doing with `merge` `indicator` , after we get the `index` need to remove , using `drop`

```
idx=df1.merge(df2,on=['vouchers','units'],indicator=True,how='left').\
     loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='both'].index
df1=df1.drop(idx,axis=0)
df1
Out[374]: 
   vouchers  units some_other_data
0       100     11               a
2       300     12               c
3       400     13               d
```

Answer (score 2):

Though we have many good answers, but the questions seems interesting so as the learning hence, i admit it in a great interest and would like to place another version which looks little simpler by using the booleans expression:

**First DataFrame:**

```
>>> df1
   vouchers  units some_other_data
0       100     11               a
1       200     12               b
2       300     12               c
3       400     13               d
```

**Second DataFrame:**

```
>>> df2
   vouchers  units some_other_data
0       500     11               a
1       200     12               b
2       600     12               c
3       300     13               d
```

**Possible Simpler answer:**

```
>>> df1[(df1 != df2).any(1)]
   vouchers  units some_other_data
0       100     11               a
2       300     12               c
3       400     13               d
```

**Solution 2:** Using `merge` + `indicator` + `query`

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator=True).query('_merge == "left_only"').drop('_merge', 1)
   vouchers  units some_other_data
0       100     11               a
2       300     12               c
3       400     13               d
```

**Solution 3:**

```
>>> df1[~df1.isin(df2).all(axis=1)]
   vouchers  units some_other_data
0       100     11               a
2       300     12               c
3       400     13               d
```

Comment: I really like the last solution for readability, but it will only work if `some_other_data` is the same in both dataframes. Could it be possibly be adjusted to work even when the data is different? (I will also adjust my question)

Comment: @barciewicz, thanks for liking it , however first answer is more robust for the provided data, if you like it you can always upvote :-)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility via [`pd.DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
df = df.loc[~df.duplicated(subset=['vouchers', 'units'], keep=False)]
df = df.reindex(df.index & df1.index)

print(df)

#   some_other_data  units  vouchers
# 0               a     11       100
# 2               c     12       300
# 3               d     13       400
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
df1 = {
    'vouchers': [100, 200, 300, 400],
    'units': [11, 12, 12, 13],
    'some_other_data': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    }
df2 = {
    'vouchers': [500, 200, 600, 300],
    'units': [11, 12, 12, 13],
    'some_other_data': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    }  

y = 0
for x in range(len(df1['vouchers'])):
    if df1['vouchers'][x-y] == df2['vouchers'][x]:
        if df1['units'][x-y] == df2['units'][x]:
            for key in df1.keys():
                del df1[key][x]
            y += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is simple:

```
excs = [] #will store the index of the values which are equal

for i, (key, value) in enumerate(zip(df1["vouchers"], df1["units"])):
  for key2, value2 in zip(df2["vouchers"], df2["units"]):
    if key == key2 and value == value2:
      excs.append(i)

for exc in excs:
  del(df1["vouchers"][exc])
  del(df1["units"][exc])
```